# Circumsphere of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra, triangulation

I'm trying to implement Bowyer-Watson algorithm. Currently performance is stuck behind calculating the circumsphere of a tetrahedron.

I tried using this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html. It works but it is slow.

Next i tried this https://www2.mps.mpg.de/homes/daly/CSDS/t4h/tetra.htm#Q1-1-7. But this has the problem of not always returning a solution. For example vertices (-1000, 0, -1000), (1000,0,-1000), (0,0,1000), (0,1000,0). I mostly keep getting -Infinity or NaN.

Is there a way to make the first one faster (leave some equations out, make some equations simpler), or make the second one always work (so that the linear equation system can handle vectors that can have 2 coordinates 0)? Or is there some third way that is even better?

EDIT

THe way i tried using to solve the linear system.

```
2d1x*x + 2d1y*y + 2d1z*z = d1^2   (1)
2d2x*x + 2d2y*y + 2d2z*z = d2^2   (2)
2d3x*x + 2d3y*y + 2d3z*z = d3^2   (3)


(2) - d2x/d1x *(1)
(3) - d3x/d1x *(1)

2d1x*x + 2d1y*y + 2d1z*z = d1^2   (1)
 0    + d2x/d1x * 2d2y*y + d2x/d1x * 2d2z*z = d2x/d1x * d2^2   (2)
 0    + d3x/d1x * 2d3y*y + d3x/d1x * 2d3z*z = d3x/d1x * d3^2   (3)

(3) - (d2y*d3x)/(d2x*d3y) *(2)

2d1x*x + 2d1y*y + 2d1z*z = d1^2   (1)
0    + d2x/d1x * 2d2y*y + d2x/d1x * 2d2z*z = d2x/d1x * d2^2   (2)
0    +    0             + (d3x*d3y)/(d2x*d2y) * 2d3z*z = dx3/d1x * 2d2y * d3^2   (3)
```

Comment: "vectors that can have 2 coordinates 0" should not cause any harm in a calculation... If there are problems, I think they are elsewhere.

Comment: Finding the center of the circumsphere is equivalent to intersecting three planes, which is what the second method does. If that’s failing, I’d suspect a bug in the way you’re solving that equation.

Comment: @amd I added in the way i tried to solve it. I tried using the gaussian elimination. But i apparently did some errors somewhere.

Comment: Oh... wait... silly me i see where i did the error :D. I used the gaussian elimination wrong....

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it out.  Numerically the linear system gets harder to solve as the four corner points approach being coplanar.  The best accuracy is squeezed out in this flattened extreme by solving with orthogonal transformations rather than elementary row operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are some alternatives.

**Alternative I** - compute barycentric coordinates of circumcenter $O$ directly.

Given a tetrahedron $T$ with vertices $v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$. Let

- $V$ and $R$ be the volume and circumradius of $T$.
- $S_i$ and $R_i$ be the area and circumradius of the face opposite to vertex $v_i$.
- $\ell_{ij}$ be the distance between vertex $v_i$ and $v_j$.

Once you have computed $V$ and $S_i$, the circumradius $R$ is given by the formula${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.

$$6VR = \sqrt{p(p-aa_1)(p-bb_1)(p-cc_1)}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\begin{cases}
a &= \ell_{01}, a_1 = \ell_{23}\\
b &= \ell_{02}, b_1 = \ell_{31}\\
c &= \ell_{03}, c_1 = \ell_{12}\\
p &= \frac12(aa_1 + bb_1 + cc_1)
\end{cases}
$$
The circumradii $R_i$ for the faces can be computed by corresponding $2$-d counterparts:
$$4S_i R_i = \prod_{j < k;\\ j \ne i,k\ne i}\ell_{jk}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
4 S_0 R_0 &= \ell_{12}\ell_{13}\ell_{23} = a_1b_1c_1\\
4 S_1 R_1 &= \ell_{02}\ell_{03}\ell_{23} = a_1 b c \\
4 S_2 R_2 &= \ell_{01}\ell_{03}\ell_{13} = ab_1 c\\
4 S_3 R_3 &= \ell_{01}\ell_{02}\ell_{13} = ab c_1
\end{cases}
$$
The barycentric coordinates for circumcenter $O$, i.e. those 
four numbers $\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_3$ such that

$$O = \sum_{i=0}^3 \lambda_i v_i\quad\text{ with }\quad \sum_{i=0}^3 \lambda_i = 1$$

is then given by the formula

$$3V\lambda_i = S_i\sqrt{R^2 - R_i^2}$$

**Alternative II** - compute circumcenter  $O$ using dot and cross products.

Same notation as previous alternative. Let $u_i = v_i - v_0$ for $i = 1,2,3$ and $p   = O - v_0$.
We have
$$R^2 = \|p\|^2 = \| u_1 - p \|^2 = \| u_2 - p \|^2 = \| u_3 - p \|^2$$
Cancelling the common term $R^2$ from these equalities, we obtain
$$
u_1 \cdot p = \frac12\ell_{01}^2,\quad
u_2 \cdot p = \frac12\ell_{02}^2,\quad\text{ and }\quad
u_3 \cdot p = \frac12\ell_{03}^2,
$$
We can invert these equations using the dual basis for the three vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$. 
The end result is following expression of $O$ which only need dot and cross products among vectors $u_k$.

$$O = v_0 + \frac{
\ell_{01}^2 ( u_2 \times u_3 ) +
\ell_{02}^2 ( u_3 \times u_1 ) +
\ell_{03}^2 ( u_1 \times u_2 )}{
2 u_1\cdot(u_2 \times u_3)}
$$

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - I. Todhunter, *Spherical Trigonometry: For the Use of Colleges and Schools*, $\S163$ (1886). An online [copy](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770) is available under Project Gutenberg.

Comment: Ten square roots seems pretty expensive.

Comment: @amd taking square roots are relatively cheap operations. it is within a factor of 2 when you compare it with division (at least for intel CPUs). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7726267/2297725) and ref there.

Comment: thank you for excellent answer, both barycentric and vector way!

Comment: Anyone know what is the most efficient for generating programs for a fixed but general dimension $d$? i.e. I think you want to solve one of the problem for a given $d$ symbolically and print that program. None of these seem generic enough to not print the symbolic inverse and cache it right?

Answer (score 6):

I'm fond of [Miroslav Fiedler](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511973611)'s method for determining the circumsphere. The starting point is the usual [Cayley-Menger matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html):

$$\mathbf C=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&d_{12}&d_{13}&d_{14}\\
1&d_{12}&0&d_{23}&d_{24}\\
1&d_{13}&d_{23}&0&d_{34}\\
1&d_{14}&d_{24}&d_{34}&0\end{pmatrix}$$

where $d_{jk}$ is the squared distance between points $\mathbf p_j$ and $\mathbf p_k$ of the tetrahedron.

From there, one computes $\mathbf M=-2\mathbf C^{-1}$, and then gets the first row of the inverse. The circumradius is given by $\frac12\sqrt{m_{1,1}}$, and the circumcenter is given by the weighted average $\dfrac{m_{1,2}\mathbf p_1+m_{1,3}\mathbf p_2+m_{1,4}\mathbf p_3+m_{1,5}\mathbf p_4}{m_{1,2}+m_{1,3}+m_{1,4}+m_{1,5}}$. (Alternatively, one can interpret the $m_{1,k}$ as unnormalized barycentric coordinates.)

---

**P.S.**

I gave a *Mathematica* demonstration of Fiedler's method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89090); the routine there also uses Cayley-Menger to compute the insphere. Here is the result of using the methods there on the OP's example tetrahedron:

[image: circumsphere and insphere]

Comment: Well i cant use this one. Im limited to using 4X4 matrix and vector2, vector3, and vector4. Anything else i need to make myself, and i cant make it as efficient as are the pre-exsisting things.

Comment: Then why did you not put those restrictions in your question?

Comment: Nice, this generalizes to any dimension too.  However, you have a typo.   $d_{jk}$ should be the _squared_ distance, not just the distance.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Layman here. After looking at the tons of square roots, inversion of 5x5 matrix, I went back to Wikipedia and read it again. While there are also tons of square roots, somewhere in the [lower-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Circumcenter) of the Tetrahedron page, there is a super-simple expression with a barycentric approach (at least that's what it looks like to me).
Of course, it's not Wikipedia, but *Lévy, Bruno; Liu, Yang (2010). "Lp Centroidal Voronoi Tessellation and its applications". ACM: 119.*

$c=M^{-1}b$ , where $M=\begin{pmatrix}
[x_1-x_0]^T\\
[x_2-x_0]^T\\
[x_3-x_0]^T\end{pmatrix}$ and  $b=\frac1 2\begin{bmatrix}
\|x_1\|^2-\|x_0\|^2\\
\|x_2\|^2-\|x_0\|^2\\
\|x_3\|^2-\|x_0\|^2\end{bmatrix}$,
$M$ is a 3x3 matrix, everything else is a column vector ($c$ will be the circumcenter, $x_0...x_3$ are the corners of the tetrahedron).

So far it appears to work for me. In fact I also needed this for Bowyer-Watson, and at the end I did not calculate a single square root, as storing $r^2=\|c-x_0\|^2$ is more efficient for an in/out comparison with Cartesian coordinates.

Ps: it's probably the same thing as "Alternative II" from the accepted answer, but that leaves a bit to the imagination.