# Sphere through four points (known from Euclid's time?)

Tags: geometry

Given four non-coplanar points in 3-space $ (x_1,y_1,z_1),\ldots,(x_4,y_4,z_4) $, find center and radius of sphere through them.

Comment: There needs to be more restrictions; if the four points are all colinear or coplanar there will not be a sphere which passes through all four.

Comment: @DuncanRamage It is clearly stated that the points are not coplanar.

Comment: @lisyarus Well, egg on my face.

Comment: I don't see the necessity to refer to Euclid, who did not use neither coordinates nor algebra.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414640/265466.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle in a plane through three points can be found  with center where two ( actually all three ) edge perpendicular bisectors meet.

A sphere ( the center of it) can be found where the plane perpendiculars through those circle centers meet

Umm. If you are given five points in general position in $\mathbb R^4,$ find the five spheres going through each set of four of the points, then the perpendiculars to the centers in each 3-plane meet in the center of the (hyper)sphere passing through all five points.

Comment: Thanks, you guessed  it right about my question.. $\mathbb R^4$ generalization. in mind

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The equation should be 
$$\left | \begin{matrix} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 & x & y & z & 1 \\
                         x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
                         x^2_2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1 \\
                         x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1 \\
                         x_4^2 + y_4^2 + z_4^2 & x_4 & y_4 & z_4 & 1                          \end{matrix} \right |  = 0 $$

Comment: see (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html   May also help?

Comment: @Narasimham: yep, that seems to be a great reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using basic algebra, write
$$(x_1-X)^2+(y_1-Y)^2+(z_1-Z)^2=R^2 \tag 1$$
$$(x_2-X)^2+(y_2-Y)^2+(z_2-Z)^2=R^2 \tag 2$$
$$(x_3-X)^2+(y_3-Y)^2+(z_3-Z)^2=R^2 \tag 3$$
$$(x_4-X)^2+(y_4-Y)^2+(z_4-Z)^2=R^2 \tag 4$$ 
Now, subtract $(1)$ from each of the other equations to get 
$$2(x_1-x_2)X+2(y_1-y_2)Y+2(z_1-z_2)Z=(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2)\tag 5$$ 
$$2(x_1-x_3)X+2(y_1-y_3)Y+2(z_1-z_3)Z=(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2+z_3^2)\tag 6$$
$$2(x_1-x_4)X+2(y_1-y_4)Y+2(z_1-z_4)Z=(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2)-(x_4^2+y_4^2+z_4^2)\tag 7$$ So, three linear equations in $X,Y,Z$. Solve them and plug the result in any of the first equations to get $R^2$.

This can easily done by hand.