# Formula for the circumcenter of a tetrahedron: What happens when the denominator is zero?

Tags: geometry, spheres

I explore the Mathstackchange for a simple formula that calculates the center of the tetrahedron circumsphere.

I find this [Circumsphere of a tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414640/circumsphere-of-a-tetrahedron). Two main approaches and some alternatives ways are mentioned in the above link.

I tried a way which also mentioned in MathWorld's ["Circumsphere"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html) entry. This approach is based on a calculate four $4\times 4$ determinants, $D_x$, $D_y$, $D_z$, and $a$; the last is
$$
a = \left|\begin{array}{cccc}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1 \\
x_4 & y_4 & z_4 & 1 \end{array}\right|
$$ Then, we have a circumsphere center via using these formulae:

$$\text{centerX} = \frac{D_x}{2 \times a}, \quad
\text{centerY}= \frac{D_y}{2 \times a},  \quad
\text{centerZ}= \frac{D_z}{2\times a} $$

I want to know:

> If the result of determinant $a$ is zero, how the center of circumsphere center is calculated?

Comment: If the determinant is zero, then the points are coplanar, meaning that a circumcenter does not exist (You could also think about it as a point at infinity, which makes sense given the division by $0$).

Comment: That $a$ determinant appears (with a constant multiplier) in the formula for the [volume of a tetrahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html). So, if it's $0$, then the tetrahedron is degenerate in some way: the vertices could be coincident, collinear, or coplanar. In the first two cases, "*the* circumsphere" is indeterminate; in the last, the circumsphere is a plane, putting the circumcenter "at infinity".

Comment: @JoshuaWang Thanks for your comment. But placing four points on a plane is not a condition which possible of forming sphere through four points. (Check: (1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (-1,0,0), (0,10))

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your comment. So this formula is based on the condition that points must form a tetrahedron. I think Your answer clear the ambiguity.

Comment: @ALIN: *"So this formula is based on the condition that points must form a tetrahedron."* More precisely: *The formula is based on the condition that the points must form a **non-degenerate** tetrahedron.* (Lots of mathematicians —myself included— allow "flat" and otherwise degenerate tetrahedra in our research.)

Comment: @blue Thanks for your subtle point.